# Convergence of $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^3+x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I'm having some confusion with inferring the convergence of

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^3+x^2}$$

This looks like a good candidate for Weierstrass M-test.

However, if one does

$$\bigg | \frac{1}{j^3+x^2} \bigg | < \frac{1}{j^3} =: M_j$$

then one is lead to prove the second property required by Weierstrass M-test, which is

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} M_j < \infty$$

But $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}$$

is well-known to be the "non-trivial" [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry's_constant).

So is the above sum's value known "well enough" so that I can show/prove that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} M_j < \infty$$

or should I do something else with my series?

Comment: Looks okay to me.

Comment: @JackyChong Although I haven't been able to find sources where the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3}$ is shown to be finite.

Comment: Use integral test.

Comment: @mavavilj Let's change the point of view: **what** convergent series *you know*?

Comment: @JackyChong Does convergence always imply finite sum? Since the convergence tests don't give sum, but rather only tell whether the sum converges or diverges.

Comment: If the sum converges, then by definition the sum is finite. You can prove finiteness of the sum without knowing exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the precise value of the limit to know convergence. Since $1/j^3$ is decreasing, we can [compare with an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{j^3} = 1 + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac1{j^3} \le 1 + \int_1^\infty \frac1{t^3}\,dt = \frac32. $$
Alternatively, we can [compare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) with the [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{j^3} < 1 + \sum_{i=2}^\infty \frac1{j^3-j} = 1 + \frac12 \sum_{i=2}^\infty \biggl[ \frac{1}{j(j-1)} - \frac{1}{(j+1)j} \biggr] = \frac54. $$

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's correct what you have calculated.

To avoid confusions with Apery's constant:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^3+x^2}\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^3}< \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

and $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is well-known.